# PHP voting intensity/force?

Tags: php, rating, drupal-fivestar

Well I'm thinking of adding a rating feature to my application where members can vote between 1-5 (this is the `$rating`) , and I display the average score like `$score = $number_of_voters / $rating`. Where `$number_of_voters` is the total count of members voted on that specific item, and `$rating` is the total rating for that specific item.

That way the `$score` can't be higher then 5 (which its out of).

However I'm thinking of integrating a voting intensity/force according to the users RPG level (which is a number between 1-8 which gradually can increase - which each member has assigned), so if for example they voted and their RPG level was 1 the average score would'nt be too different from the previous (wouldnt effect it too much) however if it was something like 8 then it would effect it more? (too summarise their RPG level would be considered internally when voting).

But not sure how to proceed (how to integrate/implement) without effecting the intial specification (ie. I don't want the score going higher then 5 (want it to be $score <= 5)).

Comment: $score = $number_of_voters / $rating ? what does that mean... do you mean $score = $number_of_voters(rating=1)/1 + $number_of_voters(rating=2)/2 etc

Comment: @Jason i've edited my intial quesiton/post with more information - please see it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your immediate question, you can multiply by a fractional weight 0-1.  If you have various levels, you can get this weight by dividing the user's level by the maximum level.

But before you get started coding, you should read [How Not To Sort By Average Rating](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html) so that you avoid some of the common pitfalls with this kind of voting system.

Answer (score 1):

Each user contributes `(weight)*(rating)` to the overall rating, so the numerator is the sum of this over all users.

The denominator is the maximum possible score, for each user this is `(weight)*5`.  Thus the denominator is the sum of this over all users.

Then compute the score as:

```
sum{ (user i's weight) * (user i's rating) } / sum{ (user i's weight) * 5 }
```

Notice however, this gives you a score in the range of 0-1, if you want the score in the range 0-5 you can normalize by 5, this removes the factor 5 in the denominator.

Supposing you had two arrays, one of ratings (the *i*-th item corresponds to the *i*-th user's rating) `$ratings` and one of weights (the *i*-th item corresponds to the *i*-th user's RPG level) `$weights` you can compute this as:

```
$numer = 0;
$denom = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($ratings); $i++){
    $numer = $weights[$i]*$ratings[$i];
    $denom = $weights[$i];
}
$avg = $numer / $denom;
```

Comment: Cheers Mark for the swift response, however I'm slightly confused on how to integrate your method, can you ellaborate on what `$ratings` is and `$weights` is (I understand their arrays, but not sure on what data they hold), please?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this... A level 1 users vote counts as 1 vote, while a level 8 users vote counts as 8 votes:

```
$thisvote = $level * $vote; 
//a user with a level 5, and a vote of 5...this is 25
$total = ($total + $thisvote) / $level + 1;
//if total was 4, 25+4 = 29, 29 / 6 = 4.83
```

This is easier than using arrays if you are not actually storing every user who voted and what their vote was.